# facebook feed dialog to be popup

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I am using below link to share my ruby on rails website content on facebook, I need this link to be popup , i am using `display=popup` as documents says, but it doesnot popsups.

```
href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=xxxx&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://www.xy.com&name="some_text"&link=http://www.xy.com/&picture="logored.jpg"+&properties=&actions="
```

what else I can try for displaying the link as popup?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Facebook DEV](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) page, you should use Facebook SDK for JavaScript in order to use modal iframe on webpage.

I've recently checked and you should read too;

> from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog
>
> If you are using the URL redirect dialog implementation, then this will be a full page display, shown within Facebook.com. This display type is called page.
>
> If you are using one of our iOS or Android SDKs to invoke the dialog, this is automatically specified and chooses an appropriate display type for the device.
>
> If you are using the Facebook SDK for JavaScript, this will default to a modal iframe type for people logged into your app or async when using within a game on Facebook.com, and a popup window for everyone else. You can also force the popup or page types when using the Facebook SDK for JavaScript, if necessary.
>
> Mobile web apps will always default to the touch display type

In order to do that, add Javascript SDK to your views/layouts/application.html.erb file just after body tag. Then use sth like this where you want to place your dialog:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```